# Find item in array of objects VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I'm making a function that searchs an array of Customers and returns a Customer object by a given ID.
I'm trying to do so with Lambda Expressions,and this is what I have so far:

```
 Public Shared Function FindCustomer(ByVal ID As Integer) As cCustomer

    Dim customer as New cCustomer = _ _
             Array.Find(arrCustomers, Function(c as cCustomer) c.ID = ID)

    Return customer

End Function
```

However,this throws a Null Reference exception at 'c',and I have no idea how to solve this,any help is welcome :).

EDIT: I get the error when I call the function like:

```
 dim cust as New cCustomer
 cust = FindCustomer(5)
 MsgBox(cust.Name)
 'BANG
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the customers in your array is null.

Comment: Or an element that's not a cCustomer.  Same problem in C# and VB.NET.

Comment: @Hans: No; he doesn't have a `TryCast`.

Comment: Oops...I did something wrong when filling my customer array, problem solved,thanks!.